# Multidimensional Data Input

Tags: arrays, vba, collections, outlook

I am currently stuck on how to implement a procedure to get and store information in VBA.

Objective:

- To get a list of agents to assign a task(s) to.
- Get a list of tasks(ticket number) for each agent
- Format information into a defined structure for email reply

Currently, I have a function that can get an agent name (isagent(sAgent)) and validate it, get a ticket number (Incident()) and validate it, and function to reply to the message with a string to format the message (sBody).

Issues:

A storage container for the data being input is my hold up. I don't believe an array is a right choice for this as the number of agents and tickets per agents can fluctuate daily.

For example: 
Yesterday's request: Reassign ticket 123 to person 1

Today's request - Reassign ticket 123, 456, and 789 to person 1. Reassign 012 to person 2, reassign 345, 678, 901, 234, and 567 to person 3

Format:

The format of the stored data needs to be returned as such:

Example -
Yesterday's request: 123 has been reassigned to person1.
Today's request:
123, 456, and 789 have been reassigned to person 1. 
012 has been reassigned to person 2.
345, 678, 901, 234, and 567 have been reassigned to person 3

Code:

This section is for the Message body format, it can be combined into one string (sBody). The variables currently are set as sIncs for ticket numbers, sXferAgent for agents, and sTense for the sentence tense.

```
'Set Body Reply
    Dim sOpen, sBody, sAddendum, sClose As String 'Message Reply Format
    sOpen = "<span style=""font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:" & vbCrLf & _
            "Arial"">Team, <o:p></o:p></span>" & vbCrLf

    sBody = "<p><span style=""font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:" & vbCrLf & _
            "Arial"">" & sINCs & " " & sTense & " been created and assigned to " & sXferAgent & "<o:p></o:p></span></p>" & vbCrLf

    sClose = "<p><span style=""font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:" & vbCrLf & _
            "Arial"">Thanks &amp; Regards,<o:p></o:p></span></p>" & vbCrLf & _
            "<p><br/></p>"

    olMsgReplyAll.HTMLBody = sOpen & sBody & sClose & sSig & olMsgReplyAll.HTMLBody
```

To get the ticket and agent formats, below is how I call them:

```
Dim sInc As String
'Receive Incident Number as AlphaNumeric
sInc = Incident()
If sInc = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If


'Receive Agent Name
sAgent = ValidateAgent
If sAgent = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Currently, my half-wit idea is as follows:

```
Sub Handoff()
    'Get reassigned tickets in loop
    'Asks for how many agents, ticket count per agent, gathers agent name and tickets for agent
    'Functions in place for get agent name, and ticket number preformatted
    'storage container issues for above process
    'Formats data into separate lines with verbiage
    Dim colReassignments As New Collection       'container for all reassignments
    Dim colAgents As New Collection              'container for agents
    Dim colTickets As New Collection             'container for tickets
    Dim ReassignCount As Integer                 '# of tickets for the agent
    Dim ReassignAgent As Integer                 'Agents to reassign to
    Dim Reassignments() As String

    'Start inquiry
    ReassignAgent = InputBox("Input number of Agents tickets being reassigned to:", "Agent Counter")
    If ReassignAgent = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    While ReassignAgent > 0
        colAgents.Add = ValidateAgent
        ReassignCount = InputBox("Input number of ticket being reassigned to agent:", "Ticket Counter")
        If ReassignCount = vbNullString Then
            Exit Sub
        End If


        For Each agent In colAgents
            For Each ticket In colTickets
                agent(x).ticket(y) = Incident()
                If agent(x).ticket(y) = "" Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                agent(x) = ValidateAgent
                If agent(x) = "" Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                ReassignCount = ReassignCount - 1
            Next ticket
        Next agent
    Wend

    'Sentence Formatting

    'Get Tense of reassignment
    If ReassignCount > 1 Then
        tense = "have"
    Else
        tense = "has"
    End If

    'Compile stored info
    'Format: "(Ticket#(s)) (tense) been reassigned to (Agent)" repeat lines as necessary

    'Process email
    'In another module
End Sub
```

Any suggestions or input is greatly appreciated. I may be overcomplicating the issue.

Updated to reflect additional modules:

```
    'Function to get ticket number
Public Function Incident()
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^(?:INC|NC|C)?([0-9]{1,8}$)"
    Dim strReplaceINC As String: strReplaceINC = "$1"
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim IncResult As Boolean

    Do
        If strPattern <> "" Then

            strInput = InputBox("Input Incident Number", "Ticket Number")

            If strInput = vbNullString Then
                Exit Function
            End If

            IncResult = False

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = True
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
                sInc = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplaceINC)
                sInc = "INC" & Format(sInc, "00000000")
                IncResult = True
            Else
                MsgBox ("Please input a valid ticket number format")
                IncResult = False
            End If
        End If

    Loop While IncResult = False
    Incident = sInc
End Function

'Function to select Agent
Public Function IsAgent(stxt As String) As Boolean
        Dim aAgent As Variant, oItem As Variant, bans As Boolean
        aAgent = Array("Bob", "Chuck", "David", "Fred", "John", "Kirk", "Paul", "Sean")
        bans = False
        For Each oItem In aAgent
            If LCase(oItem) = LCase(Trim(stxt)) Then
                bans = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        IsAgent = bans
    End Function

'Function to Validate Agent
Public Function ValidateAgent()

    'Dim sAgent As String 'Assigned Agent
    Do
        sAgent = InputBox("Please enter a the assigned agent's name:", "Pick an Assignee's Name")
        If sAgent = vbNullString Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        If sAgent <> "" Then
            If GlobalVars.IsAgent(sAgent) = True Then
                sAgent = sAgent
            Else
                MsgBox ("Incorrect Name, pick a new one!")
            End If
        End If

    Loop While GlobalVars.IsAgent(sAgent) = False
    ValidateAgent = sAgent
End Function
```

Comment: Arrays can be dynamic if you are worried about varing dimensions. You can only redim the last dimension though. You can get round this in some cases with transpose to swop last dimension temporarily/permanently.

Comment: This is begging for an object oriented solution.

Comment: Note in `Dim sOpen, sBody, sAddendum, sClose As String` only sClose is a String. The rest will be Variants.  In a list like this, you need `As String` after each variable name.

Comment: What does `agent(x).ticket(y) = Incident()` do?  `agent` and `ticket` appear to be simple variants.  I cannot think of any way they could be combined like this.

Comment: How do `sInc = Incident()` and `sAgent = ValidateAgent` work?

Comment: I would use a form rather than InputBox because I believe that would be much each for the user,  Do you know what user types are?

Comment: @TonyDallimore Incident() is posted here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482997/vba-regex-replace-loop

Comment: @TonyDallimore Modules for Agent Selection are `code` 'Function to select Agent
Public Function IsAgent(stxt As String) As Boolean
        Dim aAgent As Variant, oItem As Variant, bans As Boolean
        aAgent = Array("Bob", "Chuck", "David", "Fred", "John", "Kirk", "Paul", "Sean")
        bans = False
        For Each oItem In aAgent
            If LCase(oItem) = LCase(Trim(stxt)) Then
                bans = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        IsAgent = bans
    End Function

Comment: @TonyDallimore `'Function to Validate Agent
Public Function ValidateAgent()
    Do
        sAgent = InputBox("Please enter a the assigned agent's name:", "Pick an Assignee's Name")
        If sAgent = vbNullString Then Exit Function End If
        If sAgent <> "" Then
            If GlobalVars.IsAgent(sAgent) = True Then
                sAgent = sAgent
            Else
                MsgBox ("Incorrect Name, pick a new one!")
            End If
        End If
    Loop While GlobalVars.IsAgent(sAgent) = False
    ValidateAgent = sAgent
End Function`

Answer (score 0):

Please do not post so much code in a comment because it is difficult (impossible?) to read.  It should be added to the question.

There was a rude name for routines like `ValidateAgent` which I have forgotten.  The name hides what the routine does which is to input a validated agent.  Something like `GetValidatedAgent` would be a much better name

`InputBox` is a really clumsy way of inputting more than a single value.  If I understand correctly, the user inputs an agent, then a count and then count tickets.  There is a loop around that which allows the entry of multiple agents each with the own set of tickets.

Suppose I entered 3 and then realised there were 4 tickets? How would I fix my error?  Suppose I had entered Bob as the agent and had started entering tickets before realising I was entering Alice’s tickets.  How would I fix my error?

I would use a form.

If there was a small maximum number of agents and tickets per agent, I would probably go for a grid of text boxes.  The user would enter an agent into column 1 and the tickets into columns 2 to 5, say. I would have perhaps 10 rows.  I would validate agents and tickets when the user moved to a new text box.  I would not check consistency (for example, no ticket without an agent and no agent without a ticket) until the user clicked the submit button. I would not allow exit until the data was consistent or the user clicked the cancel button.  With this layout, the user could see their entire input on the screen and could correct any faulty agent or ticket.

Before exiting the form, the data must be saved in global variables.  I might go for the simplest which I think is an array of strings:

```
AgentA,Ticket1,Ticket2,Ticket3
AgentB,Ticket4
AgentB,Ticket5,Ticket6
  :      :      :      :
```

I would use Split to convert each string to an array when I was ready to process it.

I will discuss possible Html layouts if you confirm a maximum of about 10 agents and about 5 tickets per agent.  If there are more agents or tickets, I will suggest a different approach.

Comment: I have thought of the usage of a form, however it poses a lot of limitations as the number of tickets from past assignments has varied from 5-20. I have started to attempt doing a dictionary with a nested collection, may need to switch it to a nested array.

Comment: @Matt  (1)  The layout I suggested it unlikely to be suitable for 20 tickets.  However, a form will still be the best method of gathering so much data.  I can amend my answer for a wide variation in the number of tickets.  What is the maximum number of agents?

Comment: @Matt  (2)  You are asking questions in the wrong order.  You need to decide how to get data from the user and how to arrange that data in an email before you can decide how to hold that data.  I suspect an array or collection of strings will be the easiest method of holding the data but that cannot be confirmed until the user interface (input and output) is agreed.

Comment: @Matt  (3)  Do you agree that it is important for the user to see all the agents and tickets before committing to creation of the email?

Comment: @Matt  (4)  How important is the format of the email?  I assume clarity is a priority.  How important is a pretty appearance?  Will someone be trying to extract the data using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of trial and error, I have created something functional. I ended up creating a dictionary for Agent name input, then nested a Collection for their tickets being input(reassigned). Some of the code refers to global variables, but this is the main module for this function.

```
Option Compare Text
Public Sub Handoff_Req()
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim objItem As Object
Set objOL = Outlook.Application
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olMsgReplyAll As Outlook.MailItem
Dim IsPlainText As Boolean

'Define Product
sProduct = "HANDOFF"

'Receive Incident Number as AlphaNumeric
sInc = Incident()
If sInc = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Receive Severity level
Sev = 4

'Get reassigned tickets in loop
Dim dictReassignments As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim kagent As Variant
Set dictReassignments = New Scripting.Dictionary 'container for agents
Dim colTickets As New Collection    'container for tickets
Dim AgentCounter As Variant
Dim TicketCounter As Variant
Dim TenseCounter As Integer
TenseCounter = 0

'Get number of agents to reassign to

Line1:    AgentCounter = InputBox("Input number of Agents that tickets are being reassigned to:", "Agent Reassignment Counter")
If Not IsNumeric(AgentCounter) Then
    MsgBox (AgentCounter & " is not a number, please try again.")
    GoTo Line1
Else
    AgentCounter = CInt(AgentCounter)
End If
If AgentCounter > 5 Then
        numa = MsgBox("Do you want to input more than " & TicketCounter & " tickets for " & kagent & "?", 4, "Correct ticket amount?")
        If numa = 6 Then 'Yes
            GoTo Line2 'Continue loop
        ElseIf numa = 7 Then 'No
            GoTo Line1 'Repeat agent counter question
        End If
    End If
Line2:  While AgentCounter > 0
    Set colTickets = New Collection
    kagent = ValidateReassignedAgent
    If kagent = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Line3:  TicketCounter = InputBox("Input number of ticket(s) being reassigned to agent:", "Ticket Reassignment Counter")
    If Not IsNumeric(TicketCounter) Then
        MsgBox (TicketCounter & " is not a number, please try again.")
        GoTo Line3
    Else
        TicketCounter = CInt(TicketCounter)
    End If
    If TicketCounter > 10 Then
        numa = MsgBox("Do you want to input more than " & TicketCounter & " tickets for " & kagent & "?", 4, "Correct ticket amount?")
        If numa = 6 Then 'Yes
            GoTo Line4 'Continue loop
        ElseIf numa = 7 Then 'No
            GoTo Line3 'Repeat ticket counter question
        End If
    End If

Line4:  While TicketCounter > 0
        xInc = Reassignments()
        If xInc = "" Then
            MsgBox ("Please input a valid number")
        End If
            colTickets.Add xInc
        TicketCounter = TicketCounter - 1
    Wend
    dictReassignments.Add kagent, colTickets
    AgentCounter = AgentCounter - 1
Wend


'Check dictionary of agents
For Each agent In dictReassignments.Keys()
    'MsgBox (agent)
    sXferAgent = agent
    For Each ticket In dictReassignments(agent)
        'MsgBox (ticket)
        TenseCounter = TenseCounter + 1
        sINCs = ticket & ", " & sINCs
        sTense = "have"
    Next ticket
    'MsgBox (TenseCounter)
    If TenseCounter > 1 Then
        sTense = " have"
        sINCs = Left(sINCs, Len(sINCs) - 2)
        sINCs = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(sINCs), StrReverse(", "), StrReverse(", and "), , 1))
    Else
        sTense = "has"
        sINCs = Left(sINCs, Len(sINCs) - 2)
    End If
    sBody = "<p><span style=""font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:" & vbCrLf & _
        "Arial"">" & sINCs & " " & sTense & " been reassigned to " & sXferAgent & " per hand-off process.<o:p></o:p></span></p>" & vbCrLf
    scombined = sBody & scombined
    TenseCounter = 0
    sINCs = Null
    sTense = Null
    sXferAgent = Null
Next agent

'Process Agents for email inclusion
For Each agent In dictReassignments.Keys()
    sXferAgent = agent
    exAgent = AddXferRecip(sXferAgent)
    sXferredAgents = exAgent & "; " & sXferredAgents
Next


'Find Logged in Agent
SDagent = LoggedIn
If SDagent = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Set Category Color
Color = GetColor(SDagent)
If Color = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Get the selected item
Select Case TypeName(objOL.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
        Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objSelection.Count > 0 Then
            Set objItem = objSelection.Item(1)
        Else
            result = MsgBox("No item selected. " & _
                        "Please make a selection first.", _
                        vbCritical, "Reply All in HTML")
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Case "Inspector"
        Set objItem = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Case Else
        result = MsgBox("Unsupported Window type." & _
                    vbNewLine & "Please make a selection" & _
                    " or open an item first.", _
                    vbCritical, "Reply All in HTML")
        Exit Sub
End Select


'Change the message format and reply
If objItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set olMsg = objItem
    If olMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then
        IsPlainText = True
    End If
    olMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    Set olMsgReplyAll = olMsg.ReplyAll
    If IsPlainText = True Then
        olMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    End If


'Delete Automatic Signature
GlobalVars.DelSig olMsgReplyAll

'Remove Non-Monitored or Invalid email addresses
Dim recipremove As Variant
Dim element As Variant
    recipremove = Array("IT Service Desk")

    For lngCnt = olMsgReplyAll.Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
         Set olkrcp = olMsgReplyAll.Recipients.Item(lngCnt)
         For Each element In recipremove
         If olkrcp.Name = element Then
             If olkrcp.Type = olTo Or olCC Then
                 olMsgReplyAll.Recipients.Item(lngCnt).Delete
             End If
         End If
         Next element
     Next


   'Add recipients
    exAgent = AddXferRecip(sXferredAgents)

    'Set Recipients
    Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient
    Set olRecip = olMsgReplyAll.Recipients.Add(sXferredAgents) 'add multiple agents assigned
    olRecip.Resolve

    'BCC to SharePoint for tracking
    Set olRecip = olMsgReplyAll.Recipients.Add("Email Address")
    olRecip.Type = olBCC
    olRecip.Resolve

    'Include SD Mgr if Sev 1
    If Sev = "1" Then
        Set olRecip = olMsgReplyAll.Recipients.Add("Email Address")
        olRecip.Type = olBCC
        olRecip.Resolve
    End If

    'Delete Duplicate addresses

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim olRecip1 As Recipient, olRecip2 As Recipient
    Dim colRecipients As Recipients
    Set colRecipients = olMsgReplyAll.Recipients
        For i = colRecipients.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olRecip1 = colRecipients.Item(i)
            For j = (i - 1) To 1 Step -1
                Set olRecip2 = colRecipients.Item(j)
                If olRecip1.Name = olRecip2.Name Then
                    If olRecip1.Type = olTo Or olCC Then
                        olRecip1.Delete
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

    'Format Subject Line
    GlobalVars.SubjLine olMsgReplyAll

   'Set Signature
    sSig = SigAdd

    'Set Body Reply
    Dim sOpen As String, sAddendum As String, sClose As String 'Message Reply Format
    sOpen = "<span style=""font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:" & vbCrLf & _
            "Arial"">Team, <o:p></o:p></span>" & vbCrLf

    sBody = scombined

    sClose = "<p><span style=""font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:" & vbCrLf & _
            "Arial"">Thanks &amp; Regards,<o:p></o:p></span></p>" & vbCrLf & _
            "<p><br/></p>"

    olMsgReplyAll.HTMLBody = sOpen & sBody & sClose & sSig & olMsgReplyAll.HTMLBody

    'Get Attachments
    GlobalVars.CopyAttachments olMsg, olMsgReplyAll

    'Set Category Color
    olMsg.Categories = Color & ";Hand-off Notices"

    'Display Reply
    olMsg.Close (olSave)
    olMsgReplyAll.Display
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem



'Selected item isn't a mail item
Else
    result = MsgBox("No message item selected. " & _
                "Please make a selection first.", _
                vbCritical, "Reply All in HTML")
    Exit Sub
End If

'Cleanup
Set objOL = Nothing
Set objItem = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set olMsg = Nothing
Set olMsgReplyAll = Nothing

End Sub
```